# Geometric interpretation of Isotropic vector

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, inner-products, vector-fields

For real inner product space $(V,\langle.,.\rangle)$ there is a $\Bbb C$-bilinear form $( , )$ on $V\otimes\Bbb C$. This extension gives rise
to a Hermitian inner product, again denoted by $( , )$ on $V^2\otimes\Bbb C$. A vector
$v\in V\otimes\Bbb C$ is **isotropic** if $(v, v) = 0$.

In physics a quantity is called *isotropic* if it has the same properties or characteristics along all axes.

> **Q:** what is the geometric interpretation of isotropic vector?

**Edit:** There is a similar (maybe equal) concept known as [*Isotropic Vector Matrix*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-7485-5_9). Is this related to isotropic vector?

Comment: An element of $V\otimes \Bbb C$ admits a unique decomposition as $v\otimes 1+w\otimes i$. Writing a vector like this you find $(v\otimes 1+w\otimes i, v\otimes 1+w\otimes i )= \langle v,v\rangle -\langle w,w\rangle + 2i\langle v,w\rangle$ and you find that a vector is isotropic iff its "real" and "imaginary" parts are orthogonal and have the same norm.

Comment: @s.harp  Then one can call it something like null-Hermitian. isn't? Because the meaning of isotropic is "invariant with respect to direction". And by your comment they have same norm … but in all directions is a bit meaningless?